# Using nuxt-socket-io with Pinia

Tags: vue.js, socket.io, nuxt.js, vuex, nuxtjs3

I want to write my application like a chat on [Nuxt.Js 3](https://nuxt.com/) and use [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/) as a store. I found the [nuxt-socket-io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-socket-io) module - the easiest way for me to implement my chat. I read full [docs](https://nuxt-socket-io.netlify.app/), but only [vuex](https://nuxt-socket-io.netlify.app/configuration#vuex-options-per-socket-no-longer-recommended) usage and some kind of [iox](https://nuxt-socket-io.netlify.app/configuration#iox-options-per-socket) were mentioned there. Iox saves all the data in the state, but I need to call mutation/action from store when emitting an event on the server side. Question: how can I link nuxt-socket-io events with Pinia actions?

I tried to declare Pinia actions in vuex configuration in io.config. Then i tried to pass global [$ioState](https://nuxt-socket-io.netlify.app/configuration#iox-options-per-socket) value to Pinia state.

Comment: I wouldn't hold up much hope of this being implemented any time soon, the project owner has disabled issues on the GitHub repo, so they don't seem interested in getting feedback. I would suggest that you just use pinia in the callbacks that the module does support. I would advise against the module since this project could die quickly with the owner not willing to allow external support. iI really is a One Man Band.